# A separate page for unauthorized users or different configurations of the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making an events website using technologies like HTML, CSS, Javascript, Jquery, PHP etc. I retrieve data from a RESTful service in PHP.

There is a separate event page which is viewed both by actual intended audience and by the organizers who can edit details of the event on this page. When organizer opens the page he should see the options to edit the details of the event. But these options should not be visible to the other users. Other than these options, the page view is same for both the organizers and other users.

My question is that should i hide these options using Javascript/Jquery? Or should I have separate pages for each of the versions of this event page and direct the users according to whether he is a organizer or not? Which is preferable and why?

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for hiding sensitive data. JavaScript is on the client-side and can be manipulated by the user easily. Either you hide the information on the server-side, e.g. with PHP or you provide different event pages as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you will know if the current user is an organizer or not. Simply send back a variable in the response like **is_organizer: 1** then you can determine what to show based on the user.

If there is not much difference in the html output to the user then this method is preferable to using a completely different view as you keep your code DRY and do not have duplicates of the same markup.

I assume you already check that the user is an organizer before they can save changes to an event. If not you should definitely do so.

**UPDATE**

Here is some more info based on your recent comment.

If you're using jQuery to make and ajax call and get the data from the REST api I would do something like this (**please bear in mind that this is pseudo code**):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "event-data.php"
}).done(function(response) {
  html = "";
  //loop over events
  foreach response.events as event
    //add event html
    eventHtml = "<div class='event'>" + event.name + "</div>";
    //if organizer add edit tools
    if response.is_organizer
      eventHtml += "<div class='edit-controls'>...</div>"; 
    //concat html string
    html += eventHTML;
  //insert html to dom
  $('#content').html(html);
});
```

I don't know how you are inserting your html into the dom but this way is just an example of how you might build the html based on the user's role.

On a side note I would recommend using a front end framework for this sort of stuff. Here is a decent list:

https://github.com/showcases/front-end-javascript-frameworks

Comment: Yes i am getting the is_organizer: 1 response already. The part confusing me is "show based on the user"->should i hide the edit options using hide() in jquery then and ensure on php that even if the user gets to manipulate them he cannot add the event.Is that your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Php.
If you use Jquery to hide these fields , everyone could "unhide" these fields easily.  But you could combine these two techniques. Just Hide the fields and if somone do edits the server has to check again if the user is allowed to do changes.

Comment: Even if they did unhide the fields the server should always check who's saving what.